# How to make the title bar change color when the tab is changed

Tags: android, xml, tabs, android-titlebar

If I am on a tab in a tabbed activity, and I change tabs, how do I make the title bar and tab indicator change colors? An example of what I'm talking about can be seen below (done on paint).

[App bar changing color when different tabs are selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHaXy.png)
I figure that manipulating the different elements and what color resources that they use could be done to change everything uniformly, but at the same time, I don't know how to do that. I have four tabs, and four sets of colors picked from the material design library, red, blue, green and yellow. Including red dark, blue dark, etc.

I'm not using the default tab layout activity that comes with android studio, instead, I am using one similar to the one used here

https://androidbelieve.com/navigation-drawer-with-swipe-tabs-using-design-support-library/

minus the navigation drawer. All help would be sincerely appreciated, though I'm afraid that I'm still quite a beginner so I would appreciate it if you could make it as simple as possible.

:D

Answer (score 1):

You can just right code according to selected tab position
for tab 1

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#F00")));
```

for tab 2

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FF0")));
```

for tab 3

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#F0F")));
```

Comment: But what about the tab text color or the tab indicator color? Does the code above only change the colors seen in the title bar or all of the necessary colors?

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(color);
```

for change color title bar.